# java images to grid layout

Tags: java, image, applet

Can you add an Image to a GridLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the ImageIcon to a JLabel and add the label to the panel.

Again, using labels and Icons is discussed in the Swing tutorial. Take the time to read it!